# Size F input paramter format

Tags: c#, .net

Could you please help me in figuring out the format of height & width that SizeF function expects, if the inputs in hand is of type pixel.

Comment: "if the inputs in hand is of type pixel." What does that mean. Please edit your question and try to clarify what you have, what you want and what the problem is. Code snippets welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Page and image size in PDF is expressed in points. 1 point = 1/72 inch. You have the image size in pixels. 1 pixel = 1/96 inch. That makes 1 pixel = 3/4 points. So, when you set the SizeF, multiply the (width, height) with 0.75f.

The following code will do what you need:

```
        string imgFile = "testimg.jpg";
        System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(imgFile);
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument();
        PdfPage pdfPage = pdfDoc.AddPage(new PdfCustomPageSize((float)image.Width * 0.75f, (float)image.Height * 0.75f), new PdfMargins(0), image.Width > image.Height ? PdfPageOrientation.Landscape : PdfPageOrientation.Portrait);
        PdfImageElement pdfImage = new PdfImageElement(0, 0, image);
        pdfPage.Add(pdfImage);
        pdfDoc.Save("testimg.pdf");
        pdfDoc.Close();
```